# I can't get url's html content which is in array with DOMXpath

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping, domdocument

```
function pageContent(String $url): \DOMDocument
        {
            $html = cache()->rememberForever($url, function () use ($url) {
                return file_get_contents($url);
            });
            $parser = new \DOMDocument();
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $parser->loadHTML($html);
            libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

            return $parser;
        }
```

$linkBox is holding a website array which is like this: 
array(3) {

```
  [0]=>
  string(34) "https://lions-mansion.jp/MF161026/"
  [1]=>
  string(34) "https://lions-mansion.jp/MF171045/"
  [2]=>
  string(34) "https://lions-mansion.jp/MF171010/" 
}
```

So with foreach I try to go inside the links
but I couldn't.

```
 foreach ($linkBox as $box){
        $content = pageContent($box);
        foreach ($content as $xpathgo){
            $Pars = new \DOMXPath($xpathgo);
            $Route = $Pars->query("//ul[@id='snav']/li/a");
            foreach ($Route as $Rot){
                $get = $Rot->getAttribute('href');
            }
        }
    }

    var_dump($get);
```

It returns nothing. 
Any idea, what the problem is? Thank you for helping!

Comment: `$Route = $Pars->query("//ul[@id='snav']/li/a");` what do you want to find?

Comment: actually it returns empty array. But there is nothing wrong with the path. Because I used it just for one link this. `https://lions-mansion.jp/MF161026/` and I got what I want. But when I try to use it on a array like above. Xpath cant get the html content, I guess. But I dont  why? @KhoaTruongDinh

Comment: I will remove `cache()->rememberForever($url, function () use ($url) {` on my side.

Comment: In that array every link going different page. So every page has Url that I want. I need to write different Xpath for each link to get URL. First link's, URL is that path above. I think I need to use if statement but. I cant even get the first link's url? @KhoaTruongDinh

Comment: okay mate do, what it needs :)

Comment: I see, first of all, you cannot use `$content = pageContent($box);` for `foreach ($content as $xpathgo){`. Let me check more.

Comment: hmm, I try to iterate array and get each html content of links. I don't know how to do it except this.

Comment: yes, like you said I used that Foreach too much. when delete it, I can grab the url! Thanks, really!! @KhoaTruongDinh

Comment: So, your issue was solved?

Comment: yes! this one is solved but the next one is not! I can not use if statement very well, can you check this mate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182388/using-if-statement-to-grab-a-data-with-xpath I am really thankful!! @KhoaTruongDinh