# Using if statement to grab a data with Xpath

Tags: php, web-scraping

I have three URL and those URLs have the data that I want. But each data in the different html tag. So that's why I can't give the same Xpath for all. I need to try "if not find it this Xpath then try this." like a way. But i am bit confused to how to do that?

For example, these are the links `$linkBox`:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(34) "https://lions-mansion.jp/MF161026/"
  [1]=>
  string(34) "https://lions-mansion.jp/MF171045/"
  [2]=>
  string(34) "https://lions-mansion.jp/MF171010/"
  }
```

And I am going in those links one by one. And for the first one. I am giving Xpath:

```
$get = [];
    foreach ($linkBox as $box){
        $content = pageContent($box);
            $Pars = new \DOMXPath($content);
            $Route = $Pars->query("//ul[@id='snav']/li/a");
            foreach ($Route as $Rot){
                $get = $Rot->getAttribute('href');
            }

    }
```

But that Xpath doesn't correct for second or third one. So with if statement how can I write if it's null try this? like a code? Can I make it? or Do I need to use another way?

The second Box's Xpath is:

```
 $Route = $Pars->query("//nav[@id='siteActionNav']ul/li/a");
```

The second Box's Xpath is:

```
 $Route = $Pars->query("//ul[@id='subNavi']/li[2]/a");
```

Comment: Can you not make your array a little more detailed so it contains both URL and XPath expression? `$linkBox = [['url' => 'https://lions-mansion.jp/MF161026/', 'query' => '//ul[@id='snav']/li/a'], ...]`

Comment: i can not, I think. the reason is I am taking those with scraping. not making it myself. Already scraped urls.  @Phil

Comment: Right, that makes sense. The results from each query (your `$Route` variable) will have a `length` property (`$Route->length`). If that is `0`, then your query didn't match any elements. Can you use that to determine whether or not to run more queries?

Comment: okay, i am little bit stuck here, I can't insert length properly `if ($Route->length > 0) {
                foreach ($Route as $Rot) {
                    $get = $Rot->getAttribute('href');` could you make drop it as example answer mate? @Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is try out each XPath expression and see if it returns any elements.

For example, here's a function that tests each expression in turn, returning a `DOMNodeList` if it finds any matches, throwing an exception otherwise...

```php
function findLinks(\DOMXPath $xp) {
    $queries = [
        '//ul[@id="snav"]/li/a', 
        '//nav[@id="siteActionNav"]ul/li/a', 
        '//ul[@id="subNavi"]/li[2]/a'
    ];
    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        $links = $xp->query($query);
        if ($links->length > 0) {
            return $links; // exits the function and returns the list
        }
    }
    throw new \RuntimeException('No links found');
}
```

you can then use this like

```php
foreach ($linkBox as $box){
    $content = pageContent($box);
    try {
        $links = findLinks(new \DOMXPath($content));
        foreach ($links as $link){
            $get[] = $link->getAttribute('href'); // note: changed to a push
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "Problem with $box: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is saved me!! literally!! good function! Thank you mate really!